# Trying to add EventListener to dynamically created object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-content

I am attemping to load HTML from an external file. However upon doing so the input elements are non-interactable. I have tried this using vanilla JavaScript to no avail and just imported jQuery. My current progress is as follows:

I have a page with a static  element and a menu bar. When clicking on the menu bars icons the  elements content gets updated through JS/JQ. This is my HTML and jQuery for loading the view:

settings.html:

```
<section class="settings">
<div class="container">
    # some elements here

    <div id="graph-settings" class="settings-card">
        <i class="fa fa-chart-line fa-3x"></i><h1>Graph Settings</h1>
        <p>Web Interface Refresh Rate</p>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="graphInterval" id="graphInterval" placeholder="E.g. 2000">
        </form>
    </div>

    # more elements here
</div>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$.get("./pages/settings.html", (data) => {
    $("#main").append(data);
});

$(document).on("click", "#graphInterval", function() {
    // do something...
    console.log("test");
});
```

The content seems to be loaded correctly into the page but is not markable/interactable (dynamically added to DOM etc.). However my jQuery does not seem to find the #graphInterval element as I get no logged output from the console.

Any way to get the input fields working would be a solution. All they're needed for is to edit and retrieve it's value. I will use JavaScript to add/interact with buttons later on, no posting forms will be used, hence why the form has no "action=''".

Comment: your click handler for dynamic element should work provided that you must have unique id through out the DOM

Comment: so you are saying that your click event is not working for your dynamically added div or menu ?

Comment: The id is unique.

Exactly, the click-event does not fire for the dynamically added elements.

Comment: you have to reinitialize the listener function after the Dynamic HTML is loaded

Comment: @AravinthanK no you don't. That's the entire point of a delegated event handler.

Comment: I tried @MisirJafarov answer below, I'm assuming using

`$(document).on("click", "#graphInterval", function() {}`

is correct. Do you mean it be used directly after the `$("#main").append(data)` ?

If so that does not work either.

Comment: @EpiX0R, can you recreate your problem on jsfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: @EpiX0R your code works absolutely fine, assuming the id is set correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/524e86ys/1/. If you are still having issues check the console for errors and update the question to show a more accurate example of the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) (where you set the event listener at a high level DOM object and let all events triggered from decedents of that high level element bubble up to the high level element, any new elements added in will trigger events caught higher up. Then, in the listener, you can check to see which element actually triggered the event and act accordingly. So, in your case, remove the `id` from the `.on()` method call and then check the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) inside the listener:

```js
// Set the event listener on a high level element and capture the event
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
    // You can find out what exact element triggered the event with event.target
    console.log("event triggered by: " + event.target);
    
    // Now you can proceed as you need to:
    if(event.target.id === "heading1"){
      console.log("You clicked the heading");
    } else if(event.target.id === "para1"){
      console.log("You clicked the paragraph");
    }
});


// Create new elements
let data1 = "<h1 id='heading1'>Some new data (click me)</h1>";
let data2 = "<p id='para1'>Some new data (click me)</p>";

// Dynamically add elements to document
$(document.body).append(data1);
$(document.body).append(data2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is funny, as I tried this earlier, but if I were pressing the dynamically appended elements the e.target would return either the main or body. It was acting as if the objects were not present at all. I will try again and see if I missed something.

Comment: Issue still persists. When logging the event.target it always returns the body element. Completely ignores any dynamically appended element.

Comment: @EpiX0R Well, there must be something else happening that you're not showing because, as you can see from this example, this approach does work.

Comment: Ironically enough it was my CSS all along. For some reason a `z-index: -1;` caused the input not to be clickable...

Sorry about this, but thanks for the time spent. I've learnt a lot.